# Volume icon/settings not showing in "system tray", it did before then just disappeared

Tags: fedora, kde, gui, settings, kde4

I'm on a Fedora 21 x86_64 KDE system.... I was messing around with sound(alsamixer and pavucontrol) and after I noticed that there is no sound/volume icon in the system-tray anymore, was there before and is there on other similar systems I have.

Why is it gone? How do I bring it back?

I've tried to look in system-tray settings by right clicking somwhere on it and looking in the apps to set there..... it is not listed.

[image]
[image]